# Building Python 3 on OS X: [Python/importlib.h] Error 133

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to build Python (3.5.2) on OS X El Capitan (10.11.5). However, I run into an error when I try to `make` it. The error seems to be related to `_freeze_importlib`.

```
/usr/local/src/Python-3.5.2 $ make
if test "no" != "yes"; then \
        ./Programs/_freeze_importlib \
            ./Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py Python/importlib.h; \
    fi
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _getentropy
  Referenced from: /usr/local/src/Python-3.5.2/./Programs/_freeze_importlib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _getentropy
  Referenced from: /usr/local/src/Python-3.5.2/./Programs/_freeze_importlib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/bin/sh: line 1: 56666 Trace/BPT trap: 5       ./Programs/_freeze_importlib ./Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py Python/importlib.h
make: *** [Python/importlib.h] Error 133
/usr/local/src/Python-3.5.2 $
```

You can see my steps [on GitHub](https://github.com/lukejanicke/setups/blob/master/Python.md).

The full Terminal output up to the `make` fail is in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lukejanicke/dec964bd55633bbc5eed144300a94658).

---

*I fully acknowledge that this is an academic exercise, as El Capitan comes with Python 2.7.10 and you can easily install Python 3.5.2 with the official OS X installer package or via Homebrew.*

The documentation for [Using Python on Unix platforms](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html) provides build instructions. The documentation for [Using Python on a Macintosh](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) specifically says to use the the OS X installer package.

However, it should be possible to build on Mac.

> Python on a Macintosh running Mac OS X is in principle very similar to Python on any other Unix platform, but there are a number of additional features such as the IDE and the Package Manager that are worth pointing out.

At this point, I'm not worried about those additional features. Just curious about why I am getting a `make` error.

Comment: a bit unrelated considering you want to build it on your own, but does
`brew install python3` help you?

Comment: Yes, I went with Homebrew but I remain curious about building it.

Comment: Does adding `--enable-universalsdk` to `configure` resolve the issue?

Comment: Tried with `--enable-universalsdk` but the same error pops out.

Comment: I wonder if it matters that `./configure` chose to configure with Xcode-beta, which I just installed a few days ago.

Comment: Regarding a comment in the OP, I think that installing CPython from source on macOS does have considerable practical value: it enables you to install the latest version (which doesn't ship from Apple), a development version, or multiple versions (2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, etc.). Doing so is flat, not nested within MacPorts or other layers. Flat is better than nested [PEP 20].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed.

In the output of `./configure`, I noticed a reference to `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/`. I installed Xcode 8 (beta) a few days ago. After switching back to the regular Command Line Tools (with Xcode 7.3.1)

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

`make` succeeded. Not perfectly.

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _sqlite3           
_ssl                  nis                   ossaudiodev        
spwd                  zlib                                     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Failed to build these modules:
_lzma                 _tkinter
```

I hope I don't need those modules.

I've put the full output of `./configure` and `make` in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lukejanicke/5615c254c4c12bbde008439765f64f03). I didn't include the output for `make install` as it was too long and seemed to only repeat the warnings and errors of `make`.

**Notes**

- I didn't use `--enable-framework` or `--enable-universalsdk`.

Comment: I got a similar error, perhaps for a different reason--though with Xcode 8 (on macOS Sierra 10.12.6). What worked in my case was to place default paths (`/usr/...`) before MacPorts (regarding `gcc`), and cleaning with `make distclean` inside the [CPython repository](https://github.com/python/cpython).

Answer (score 5):

I think a better solution is `xcode-select --install`.

If you update Xcode to 8(beta), you have to run `xcode-select --install` again to install all the build tools with it.

I ran into the same issue as yours and I can successfully install python through brew with Xcode8 after running `xcode-select --install`.

I hope it would help others with the same issue here.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting Symbol not found: _getentropy and this helped me resolve the issue and continue with installing python3 (brew install --upgrade python3).